# Logstash multiline input works on local but not on EC2 instance

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

I've tried to parse it using the json, json_lines and even the multiline input plugin, yet to no avail. The multiline works well on my local machine but doesn't seem to work on my s3 and ec2 instance.

How would I write the grok filter to parse this?

This is what my JSON file looks like

```
{  
       "sourceId":"94:54:93:3B:81:6F1",
       "machineId":"c1VR21A0GoCBgU6EMJ78d3CL",
       "columnsCSV":"timestamp,state,0001,0002,0003,0004",
       "tenantId":"iugcp",
       "valuesCSV":"1557920277890,1,98.66,0.07,0.1,0.17 ",
       "timestamp":"2019-05-15T11:37:57.890Z"
}
```

This is my config -

```
input {
file{
         codec => multiline
        {
            pattern => '^\{'
            negate => true
            what => previous                
        }
        path => "/home/*myusername*/Desktop/data/*.json"
        start_position => "beginning"
        sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
}
}
filter {

 mutate
    {
        replace => [ "message", "%{message}}" ]
        gsub => [ 'message','\n','']
    }
    if [message] =~ /^{.*}$/ 
    {
        json { source => message }
    }

}
```

//Output tag is correct, haven't included it here

The results I get is just the json file present in the "message" field.
What I wanted is for every json tag, there should be a separate field in the document.